# SharePoints on VMWare Workstation. Need to access the SP from non-domain desktop

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, virtual-machine, access

1. I installed VM-Workstation and added 2 VM (1 vm for AD domain controller and 2nd VM for play SP 2010)
2. I dont want my home desktop to be part of the domain that I created for play sp2010
3. I can access the SP2010 from my desktop using the machine/computer name. Both Central Admin and portal are accessible using computer name.
4. I added portal.spplay.com and it resolves when I am on the either vm (ad or sp)
5. I added a host entry (192.168.10.50 portal.spplay.com) on the desktop which is not a part of any domain.
6. I ping portal.spplay.com and it does point to the above ip address but then I get request timed out.
7. From, desktop ie browser i can not access portal.spplay.com

What are my options now?

Comment: This sounds like a VMWare networking problem. Can you ping the IP addresses of either your VMs from your desktop?

Comment: How is your firewall set on the VMs? Allow all? Allow Domain?

Comment: Ping ip from desktop gets timed out.

Comment: Firewall on sp is totally off. Inbound for sp is set to accept all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. finally, I found a article and it helped me right away...

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/vmware/allow-access-to-a-vmware-virtual-machinenat-from-another-computer/

1. Went to "Virtual Network Editor" from my host computer (found under VMWare menu)
2. Change the IP address for the NAT subnet ip to 192.168.10.0
3. Followed the article above for more on NAT settings

Bingo... i can now do portal.spplay.com from my host pc.